# need help navigating to different pages for restaurant app

Tags: reactjs, navigation

I am trying to create a restaurant app that lets users navigate to pages that include additional information about each restaurant they are interested in. Sort of like each block in my code would have its own separate Restaurant page with ratings and reviews...etc. Not sure if i explained that properly. Here is some the code :

```
   <header>South End Eateries</header>
        <div className = "restaurant-list">
            {restaurants.map ((restaurant) => 
            <div>
               <div className="restaurant-block">
               <a href={restaurant.website}><h3 className="restaurant-name">{restaurant.name}</h3></a><br/>    
                <h2><img src={restaurant.picture_url} className="restaurant-pics" alt=""></img></h2>
                <h2 className="restaurant-address">{restaurant.address?.street} {restaurant.address?.suite}</h2>
                <h4 className="restaurant-price">{priceSign(restaurant.price)}</h4>
                <h3 className="restaurant-distance">Distance from Tech Hub: {restaurant.distance_in_miles}</h3>
                
            </div>
               </div>
                
            
            )}
        </div>
```

```
function App() {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme='light' font='fellix'>
      <GlobalCSS />
    <div className="App">
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<HomePage/>} />
        <Route path="/feedback" element={<FeedbackPage/>} />
        <Route path="/about" element={<AboutPage />} />
        <Route path="/login" element={<LoginPage />} />
        <Route path="/reviews" element={<ReviewPage />} /> 
        <Route path="/sortbydistance" element={<DistanceSortedPage />} /> 
        <Route path="/sortbyprice" element={<PriceSortedPage />} /> 
        <Route path="/restaurant/:id" element={<RestaurantPage />} /> 
      </Routes>
    
    </div>
    </ThemeProvider>

  );
}
```

These are my route paths from another folder
I have tried enclose it in an h ref and a few other things but i feel like I am wayyyy off the mark. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.